# Command to perform "Prepare for Shutdown" task

Tags: hudson, hudson-api

Is there a command that will put the hudson in maintenance mode. I mean, before shutting down the Hudson we first need to click "Prepare for Shutdown" button in "Manage Hudson" UI page, is it possible to do the above task from command-line.

Im writing a script to maintain the hudson - where in first i need to shutdown hudson, upgrade hudson, start hudson.

there are commands for Shutdown and start of Hudson. Looking for command that will prepare hudson for shutdown.

Answer (score 3):

http://your-server-name/hudson/quietDown

You should be able to call that address using `wget` in Linux to put Hudson into "prepare for shutdown" mode. Not sure how you would do that in Windows, though.

Comment: Another option is to use Hudson CLI:
`java -jar hudson-cli.jar -s http://your-server-name quiet-down`

Comment: @girishs: you're welcome! Glad it worked. Could you please accept the answer so other people can know it is correct?